# Minimize the number of operation to make all elements of array equal

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of n elements you are allowed to perform only 2 kinds of operation to make all elements of array equal.

1. multiply any element by 2
2. divide element by 2(integer division)

Your task is to minimize the total number of above operation performed to make all elements of array equal.

Example

array = [3,6,7] minimum operation is 2 as 6 and 7 can be divided by 2 to obtain 3.

I cannot think of even the brute force solution.

Constraints 
1 <= n <= 100000 and
1 <= ai <=100000
where ai is the ith element of array.

Comment: Mention the constraints maybe

Comment: Don't forget to post constraints, the're rly inportant!

Comment: Brute force can be fast too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. View all numbers as strings of `0` and `1`, via their binary expansion.

E.g.: `3, 6, 7` are represented as `11, 110, 111`, respectively.

2. Dividing by `2` is equivalent to removing the right most `0` or `1`, and multiplying by `2` is equivalent to adding a `0` from the right.

For a string consisting of `0` and `1`, let us define its "head" to be a substring that is the left several terms of the string, which ends with `1`.
E.g.: `1100101` has heads `1`, `11`, `11001`, `1100101`.

3. The task becomes finding longest common head of all the given strings, and then determining how many `0`'s to add after this common head.

---

An example:

Say you have the following strings:

`10101001`, `101011`, `10111`, `1010001`

1. find the longest common head of `10101001` and `101011`, which is `10101`;
2. find the longest common head of `10101` and `10111`, which is `101`;
3. find the longest common head of `101` and `1010001`, which is `101`.

Then you are sure that all the numbers should become a number of the form `101 00...`.

To determine how many `0`'s to add after `101`, find the number of consecutive `0`'s directly following `101` in every string:

For `10101001`: 1

For `101011`: 1

For `10111`: 0

For `1010001`: 3

It remains to find an integer `k` that minimizes `|k - 1| + |k - 1| + |k - 0| + |k - 3|`. Here we find `k = 1`. So every number should becomd `1010` in the end.

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution. Once you observe the shape of the solution (prefix follows by zeros) it is really easy.

Comment: @WhatsUp how to efficiently find k?

Comment: In view of your constraints, it is even possible to do it by bruteforce: try every `k` from `0` to `20`, say.

Comment: I've replaced my answer by an implementation of this. I've did it by brute force, if this is not fast enough, than you could group the numbers per numbers of 0 after the prefix, as this is the only thing that matters and turn this into a factor.

Comment: Does this answer adhere to the requirements of the question? Only two types of operations are allowed; multiply by two and divide by two. A binary expansion would require more operations, and additional calculations such as addition or subtraction would also go beyond the scope of the initial question requirements. The result is correct but the journey seems to go out of bounds. Maybe I am misreading the question?

Comment: @Jay I'm afraid you are misreading the question, Jay. Given an array, you must use the two types of operations to achieve the goal that all numbers in the array are equal. The question is to find the MINIMUM number of operations needed. The CALCULATION of this minimum number, however, doesn't need to be limited to multiplying and dividing by two.

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the answer and the followup answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer explains, backtracking is not necessary. For the fun of it a little implementation of that approach. (See link to run online at the bottom):

First we need a function that determines the number of binary digits in a number:

```
    def getLength(i: Int): Int = {
         @annotation.tailrec
         def rec(i: Int, result: Int): Int =
           if(i > 0)
             rec(i >> 1, result + 1)
           else
             result
         rec(i, 0)
   }
```

Then we need a function that determines the common prefix of two numbers of equal length

```
   @annotation.tailrec
   def getPrefix(i: Int, j: Int): Int =
         if(i == j) i
         else getPrefix(i >> 1, j >> 1)
```

And of a list of arbitrary numbers:

```
   def getPrefix(is: List[Int]): Int = is.reduce((x,y) => {
         val shift = Math.abs(getLength(x) - getLength(y))
         val x2 = Math.max(x,y)
         val y2 = Math.min(x,y)
         getPrefix((x2 >> shift), y2)
   })
```

Then we need the length of the suffix without counting leeding zeros of the suffix:

```
    def getSuffixLength(i: Int, prefix: Int) = {
         val suffix = i ^ (prefix << (getLength(i) - getLength(prefix)))
         getLength(suffix)
    }
```

Now we can compute the number of operations we need to synchronize an operation i to the prefix with "zeros" zeros appended.

```
    def getOperations(i: Int, prefix: Int, zeros: Int): Int = {
         val length = getLength(i) - getLength(prefix)
         val suffixLength = getSuffixLength(i, prefix) 
         suffixLength + Math.abs(zeros - length + suffixLength)
    }
```

Now we can find the minimal numbers of operations and return that together with the value we will sync to:

```
    def getMinOperations(is: List[Int]) = {
        val prefix = getPrefix(is)
        val maxZeros = getLength(is.max) - getLength(prefix)
        (0 to maxZeros).map{zeros => (is.map{getOperations(_, prefix, zeros)}.sum, prefix << zeros)}.minBy(_._1)
    }
```

You can try this solution at:

http://goo.gl/lLr5jl

The last step of finding the right number of zeros can be improved, as only the length of a suffix without leading zeros matters, not what it looks like. So we can compute the number of operations we need for these together by counting how many there are:

```
    def getSuffixLength(i: Int, prefix: Int) = {
         val suffix = i ^ (prefix << (getLength(i) - getLength(prefix)))
         getLength(suffix)
    }

    def getMinOperations(is: List[Int]) = {
        val prefix = getPrefix(is)
        val maxZeros = getLength(is.max) - getLength(prefix)
        val baseCosts = is.map(getSuffixLength(_,prefix)).sum
        val suffixLengths: List[(Int, Int)] = is.foldLeft(Map[Int, Int]()){
            case (m,i) => {
                val x = getSuffixLength(i,prefix) - getLength(i) + getLength(prefix)
                m.updated(x, 1 + m.getOrElse(x, 0))
            }
        }.toList
        val (minOp, minSol) = (0 to maxZeros).map{zeros => (suffixLengths.map{
           case (x, count) => count * Math.abs(zeros + x)
        }.sum, prefix << zeros)}.minBy(_._1)
        (minOp + baseCosts, minSol)
    }
```

All axillary operations only take logarithmic time in the size of the maximal number. We have to go through the hole list to collect the suffix lengths. And then we have to guess the number of zeros where there are at most logarithmic in the maximal number many zeros. So we should have a complexity of

```
O(|list|*ld(maxNum) + (ld(maxNum))^2)
```

So for your bounds this is basically linear in the input size.

This version can be found here:

http://goo.gl/ijzYik